# Disable single radio choice from Grouped Radio Action Buttons

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyjs

I have a below shiny code, I am trying to disable single radio button choice from grouped radio buttons. 
I can disable complete radio button using `shinyjs::disable()` function. But, having trouble disabling single choice.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    radioGroupButtons(inputId = "somevalue", choices = c("A", "B", "C")),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderText({ input$somevalue })

    shinyjs::disable(id="somevalue")

  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
runjs("$('input[value=B]').parent().attr('disabled', true);")
```

or

```
runjs('$("#somevalue button:eq(1)").attr("disabled", true);')
```

or

```
disable(selector = "#somevalue button:eq(1)")
```

Comment: is it possible for us to achieve this using `shinyjs::disable` function? Because, I want to enable and disable based on selectors.

Comment: @RushabhPatel This is my third solution. No need to write `shinjs::` when `shinyjs` is loaded.

Comment: For the first of these answers, how does it identify for which input it should disable? If there were two radiogroupbuttons with the value B as a response, would it just disable them both?